# WP8, how to create and write data into an excel file

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I m looking for a way to create an excel file in WP8, and then add data in the 1,2 and 3rd column.

How can i create an excel file, and a method to write data in the file's first 3 column, and in new line, every time i call it?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the epplus libary: 
http://epplus.codeplex.com/ It's a free library which wraps the Open XML SDK (the Microsoft library for writing / reading xlsx documents) and is a huge performance / usabillity improvement since raw open xml sdk is VERY painful to program.

Comment: i will take a look! it looks promising